# Run perl when system() is disabled

Tags: php, perl, passthru

I'm trying to run a Perl script using:

```php
$var = null;
system(PATH_PERL . 'script.pl', $var);
var_dump($var);
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> `Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons [...]`

The complete list of disabled functions (with `ini_get('disable_functions')`):

> `system, system_exec, shell, shell_exec, exec, passthru, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, proc_close, proc_open, ini_alter, popen, show_source, enable _dl, dl`

**Is there any way to execute a Perl script when these functions are disabled?**

Comment: what returns `print ini_get("disable_functions");`?

Comment: @bwoebi I added the list to the question

Comment: Write Perl interpreter and VM implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to execute them by shell; all ways to execute shell commands in PHP are disabled. (execpt interpreting perl in PHP (what makes no sense I think...; then you also can directly translate perl to php))

Comment: @CamilStaps Which host do you use?

Comment: [Neostrada](http://neostrada.nl), but it's Dutch. They're pretty soon with support questions and don't care about installing pecl and such if you ask for it, so perhaps...

Comment: @CamilStaps I don't think they'll allow it, as it is the only way (without chrooting and having different apaches etc) to prevent users to see other users data on the same server ;)

Comment: Okay, well we'll see :) worth a try

Comment: For reference: fortunately, there was a PHP version of the script already. That's an option for one too thus (it's basically the same as translating of course, but without the work).